# Consulta obteber Registros entre una hora inicial y una final

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta para validar si en un horario específico ya existe una cita, ya que en el mismo lapso de tiempo no se debe generar otra cita. Para ello consulto la fecha de la cita, la hora inicial de la cita y la hora final.

Mi tabla de citas está así:

[image: Tabla de citas]

Entonces mi consulta que más o menos me funcionó:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("select * from events where ((e_time_start < ? AND e_time_end > ?) OR e_time_end > ? AND e_time_end < ? OR e_time_start > ? AND e_time_start < ?) AND e_date_event = ?;");
$query->execute([$time_start.':00', $time_end.':00', $time_start.':00', $time_end.':00', $time_start.':00', $time_end.':00', $date_start.'']);
$events = $query->fetchAll();
```

Debería de solucionar los siguientes eventos con respecto a la información que tengo en la tabla pero en ciertos casos no me los soluciona:

6am a 7am   sí debe poder agregar la cita
7am a 8am   no debe poder agregar la cita
6am a 11am  no debe poder agregar la cita
8am a 11am  no debe poder agregar la cita
8am a 9am   no debe poder agregar la cita
9am a 10am  no debe poder agregar la cita
10am a 11am sí debe poder agregar la cita

Comment: Hola Christopher Flores, bienvenido a Stack Overflow! Te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso tener la oportunidad de ganar tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ya consulta que esta haciendo esta un poco loco, hay una funcion llamada BETWEEN  que realizar una consulta por rango o se utiliza para recuperar valores dentro de un rango en una consulta

```
SELECT * FROM `asistencias` WHERE 
fecha_inicial BETWEEN '2018-01-00 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-31 00:00:00' 
AND 
fecha_final BETWEEN '2018-01-00 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-31 00:00:00'
```

or puede intertar con

```
SELECT * from events where 
e_time_start  between '08:00:00' and '06:00:00' and
e_time_end between '08:00:00' and '06:00:00' 
AND e_date_event = '2018-03-16'
OR 
(e_time_start< '08:00:00' and e_time_end > '06:00:00' ) AND e_date_event = '2018-03-16'
```

Comment: Hola Marcos yo hice esa consulta justo asi mira `select * from events where (e_time_start between '06:00:00' and '08:00:00') and (e_time_end between '06:00:00' and '08:00:00') AND e_date_event = '2018-03-15';` pero aun asi no me funciona

Comment: quitele los () y listo, el between funciona para dos rangos      'select * from events where e_time_start between '06:00:00' and '08:00:00' and e_time_end between '06:00:00' and '08:00:00' AND e_date_event = '2018-03-15'';

Comment: le dejo un ejemplo: "table_1" between "rango 1" AND "Rango 2"

Comment: Hola Marcos ya lo hice como me dijiste `select * from events where e_time_start between '06:00:00' and '08:00:00' and e_time_end between '06:00:00' and '08:00:00' AND e_date_event = '2018-03-15';` sin embargo aun no funciona yo en mi tabla tengo un registro de 7am a 10am de esa misma fecha, se supone que me deberia arrojar un registro pero no lo hace.

Comment: me toco crear la base de dato ,intente con el siguientes codigo select * from events where e_time_start between '08:00:00' and '06:00:00' and e_time_end between '08:00:00' and '06:00:00' AND e_date_event = '2018-03-16' OR (e_time_start< '08:00:00' and e_time_end > '06:00:00' )

Comment: Y te funciono? voy a probarlo

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Te debo 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM citas WHERE 
(_fecha_event=DATE(fecha_inicio) ) AND 
(
    (_fecha_inicio>=fecha_inicio AND _fecha_fin<=fecha_fin) 
OR 
    (_fecha_inicio<=TIME(fecha_inicio) AND _fecha_fin>TIME(fecha_inicio) )
OR
    (_fecha_fin>TIME(fecha_inicio) AND _fecha_inicio<TIME(fecha_fin) )
);
```

Yo separe la fecha y la hora para poder trabajar mas fácil a mi parecer

La función `DATE` te saca la fecha de un campo tipo `DATETIME` es decir elimina la hora y se queda solo con la fecha y la función `TIME` te elimina la fecha y te deja solo la hora

- `_fecha_event` es la fecha en formato date Ejem: **"2020-01-30"**
- `_fecha_inicio` es la hora de inicio Ejem: **"08:00"**
- `_fecha_fin` es la hora de finalización Ejem: **"09:00"**

Lo puse así porque definí esta consulta como un procedimiento almacenado pero ustedes pueden reemplazarlo por sus propias variables y comprobar si cumple sus necesidades.

Esta consulta te regresa los registros que coincidan con las horas ingresadas por el usuario es decir si metes x día a x horas te regresara uno o mas registros si esa hora elegida no esta disponible y si te regresa 0 resultados quiere decir que las horas seleccionadas si están disponibles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esa consulta cumple con las necesidades especificadas en la pregunta y es la que yo utilice en mi proyecto